# Tensorflow QueueRunner with py_func enqueue_op: How to use?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use a custom `py_func` `enqueue_op` with `TensorFlow` `RandomShuffleQueue` and `QueueRunner`. I am very new to `TensorFlow` and is very confused. Here is what I have now:

```
def compute_data(symbol, time):
    data = np.zeros((1330,))
    return data

key_1 = [str(x) for x in range(3000)]
key_2 = [str(y) for y in range(4800)]
tf_k1 = tf.constant([k for k in k1])
tf_k2 = tf.constant([k for k in k2])
tf_k1_index = tf.random_uniform((1,), minval=0, maxval=len(k1), dtype=tf.int32, name='k1_index')
tf_k2_index = tf.random_uniform((1,), minval=0, maxval=len(k2), dtype=tf.int32, name='k2_index')
tf_k1_variable = tf.gather_nd(tf_symbols, tf_k1_index)
tf_k2_variable = tf.gather_nd(tf_times, tf_k2_index)
tf_compute_data = tf.py_func(compute_data, [tf_k1_variable, tf_k2_variable], tf.float32, name='py_func_compute_data')
```

Basically what I'm trying to achieve here is that **given two sets of keys, randomly sample a combination of the two keys each time and generate a piece of data given those two keys**. The data generation process involves a lot of file reading and is skipped for now because I want to build the graph properly first.

And here is the rest of the code that should enqueue the result of `tf_compute_data` into `queue`.

```
queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(
    capacity=20000, 
    min_after_dequeue=2000, 
    dtypes=[tf.float32], 
    shapes=[[1330]], 
    name='data_queue'
    )

enqueue_op = queue.enqueue(tf_compute_data)
tf_data = queue.dequeue_many(batch_size)

...

qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue, [enqueue_op] * 4)
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir="logdir")
with sv.managed_session(config=config, start_standard_services=True) as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    enqueue_threads = qr.create_threads(sess, coord=coord, start=True)

    for step in xrange(1000000):
        if coord.should_stop():
            break
        sess.run(train_op)
        print step

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(enqueue_threads)
```

When I run the script, error shows as this:

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Out of range: RandomShuffleQueue '_0_data_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 64, current size 0)
     [[Node: data_queue_DequeueMany = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](data_queue, data_queue_DequeueMany/n)]]
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Out of range: RandomShuffleQueue '_0_data_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 64, current size 0)
     [[Node: data_queue_DequeueMany = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](data_queue, data_queue_DequeueMany/n)]]
```

When I add logging to the `compute_data` function it shows that it only ran 4 times, once per thread. How do I make it run as long as `coord.should_stop()` is `False`?

Comment: All of the ops need to be defined in the same graph; I'd suggest either taking out the `with tf.Graph().as_default():` call (which creates a new graph), or defining all of the ops inside of that scope.

Comment: @AllenLavoie Wow what a stupid mistake I made! Thank you for pointing that out. I've updated the code and it is still showing some error that I don't know how to fix. Can you help me with this too?

Comment: The queue closed errors are odd since you've joined the enqueue threads, but that's happening just at the end, right (i.e. the looping happens fine)? On the "only ran 4 times" issue, you may just need to pass `stateful=True` to py_func.

Comment: @AllenLavoie Could it be that the `queue` is never opened? `stateful` shouldn't be the reason because it is defaulted to be `True`. I tried to set it to `True` manually and nothing changes when I run.

Comment: I had to modify your code a bit to run it (some variables seem to be defined elsewhere), but the only other error I ran into was the dtype of the py_func return. It's declared in the code as returning `tf.float32`, but by default numpy's dtype is float64; adding `dtype=np.float32` to the `np.zeros` call in `compute_data` got it iterating for me (still going at the moment).

Comment: @AllenLavoie That solved my problem! Thank you very much! Can you put it in answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to summarize the comments, there were two issues:

First, `with tf.Graph().as_default()` starts things over from scratch, so everything needs to be re-defined in that new graph.

Second, the `dtype` returned by a `py_func` is a bit tricky, since numpy defaults to `float64` while most TensorFlow functions default to `float32`. So when defining a `py_func` it may be necessary to explicitly set the `dtype` of numpy arrays to `float32`. There is an error message for this, but I think it got written to a different stream (so if you've arrived at this page for a similar queue error and a `py_func` `dtype` match isn't the issue, make sure you check both `stdout` and `stderr` for the underlying error).